# Genymotion and Virtual box on ssd or hdd

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I have ssd and hdd. So I want to install Genymotion and virual box on ssd. But when I install programs on geny motion emulator the programs will be installed on the ssd and I want to avoid recent writes on it. I know that I can move genymotions emulators on hdd (from options), but I don't know where they are installed. So where app is installed for an emulator? In it's folder (where it is downloaded from genymotion) or ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the deployed virtual machines' disks are stored in `~/.Genymotion/deployed/<name>`. On Windows, they're found in `c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\<name>`.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. So is there a way to change only this disks folders (because I want then on my hdd)?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?